# in a yaml file, use the output of one target function as input parameters for a different function

Tags: python, yaml

I have a python script that uses a yaml file to call a function. Currently it is formatted like this:

```
name: DataSet
_target_: some.function.here
_params_:
  root: ${paths.datadir}
  label_name: label
  version: 0.1.0
  log_level: ${log_level}
```

I have another function, `my.label.function` that takes two parameters. I would like to be able to specify what parameters to use for this function in the same yaml file, or a different yaml file. Then pass the output of the function as the input parameter `label_name` but I am new to working with config files so I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: At the root of your YAML document you have a mapping where the value for key `_name` determines the function name to be called. Since keys have to be unique, you'll have to change your data structure, e.g. by the root a sequence each item of of which is a mapping with a `_name` key. That way the order in which the functions are called is determined, there are other solutions in which this might not necessarily be the case. The changed data structure in your document will need compatible changes in your Python code that processes the data loaded from the YAML document.

Comment: @Anthon I understand that. My question is how I specify that the output of one function is used as input to the next function within the yaml file

Comment: *There is no such thing a "function within the YAML file"* So there is nothing in the YAML file that can call something else. You can have a program that interpreters a scalar loaded from a YAML document, e.g. based on a leading `$` character. Any changes in how that program interprets the scalars and how those interpretations relate to each other (e.g. simulating one function calling another), all happen by changing that program. YAML just provides the scalars and  the hierarchical relation between them.